# Getting a lost passport replacement in the UK within a day?

Tags: uk, passports

What is the likelihood of the UK passport agency being nice and fast tracking my hubby's lost passport in a day? I have seen some web posts of it happening.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot use the 1-day premium service (https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/cost - "Unavailable" in table for lost passports) Therefore, if you have lost the passport, you must use the Fast Track 1-week premium service available here: https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently

You will have to receive the passport via the standard Royal Mail special delivery service and you'll have to be in to receive it.

Comment: Can you give a citation for this? I might be mistaken, but I couldn't find any prohibition on using the premium service for replacement passports.

Comment: The citation is in the link provided, I'll expand the answer accordingly.

Comment: I see now, will delete my answer.